# Android:Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to convert an activity to a fragment to be able to use it in my navigation drawer but I have some errors

that's the activity

```
public class RecyclerViewActivity extends Activity {

private List<Person> persons;
private RecyclerView rv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recyclerview_activity);


    rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);

    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();
}

private void initializeData(){
    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "23 years old", R.drawable.emma));
    persons.add(new Person("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old", R.drawable.lavery));
    persons.add(new Person("Lillie Watts", "35 years old", R.drawable.lillie));
    persons.add(new Person("ass","ass",R.drawable.lillie));
    persons.add(new Person("sfs","sfs",R.drawable.lavery));
    persons.add(new Person("fdfd" , "sfdfe" ,R.drawable.emma));
}

private void initializeAdapter(){
    RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(persons);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

---

that's the fragment after I converted it

```
public class RecyclerViewActivity extends Fragment {

private List<Person> persons;
private RecyclerView rv;
public static final String TAG = "REC";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_activity, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    rv = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rv);

    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();}

private void initializeData() {
    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "23 years old", R.drawable.emma));
    persons.add(new Person("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old", R.drawable.lavery));
    persons.add(new Person("Lillie Watts", "35 years old", R.drawable.lillie));
    persons.add(new Person("ass", "ass", R.drawable.lillie));
    persons.add(new Person("sfs", "sfs", R.drawable.lavery));
    persons.add(new Person("fdfd", "sfdfe", R.drawable.emma));
}

private void initializeAdapter() {
    RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(persons);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

---

I have an error in (this) in linear layout manger initialization

Comment: try getActivity().this

Comment: thanks it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `this` with `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace:

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
```

with

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

Comment: You're welcome! Any chance to vote my answer up and mark it as correct? :)